# What is the difference between abstract class and interface in terms of their storage in JVM

Tags: java, interface, jvm, abstract-class

What is the difference between abstract class and interface in terms of their storage in JVM. To be more precise where does JVM store interfaces into its memory?

Comment: Heap, since interfaces only exists as implementations in classes and they are on the heap.

Comment: Is this purely informational or are you trying to achieve something?

Comment: It depends on the JVM because the JVM specs don't say how the memory should be organised...

Comment: Can't be found.... Depends on JVM... There is not an answer... Even in the docs...

Comment: also all values in interface are constants i.e final static, so it's stored on Heap only.

Comment: @Alex: I have asked this question for informational purpose only.

Comment: @Hiru: Since for classes we have heap, stacks, class information area so does the same happen with the case of Interfaces as well, as they too have methods(though not with implementation), variables also.

Comment: Yes @ShardaPrasadJaiswal the compiler will make methods of interface as abstract and variables as static final means CONSTANTS!! and it's stored on Heap only!!

Comment: This http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html explains the internal architecture of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Comment: You mean the interfaces themselves? (As opposed to instances of classes which implement them)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Warning:* As was mentioned by @assylias, this mechanics are specific for Oracle HotSpot JVM.

**Before Java8**

All meta information is stored in PermGen, for both abstract classes and interfaces. Meta information includes only class specific information (what fields it has, what is parent, etc).

Interface can have only `public static final` fields, so this field meta information is stored in PermGen.

Abstract class can have both static and non-static fields. However, there is no difference in terms of meta information, so it is all stored in PermGen too. On the other hand, real object instances are stored in Heap for both static and non-static fields.

See the example

```
public class MyClass {
   public static final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   private Date myDate = new Date();
}
```

Field information about `calendar` and `myDate` is stored in PermGen and real object instances are stored in Heap.

In **Java8** PermGen was moved inside the Heap space, in so-called Metaspace, so you will not see `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` anymore. However, conceptual separation between meta information and object allocation memory is still present.

Also review @AlexTaylor specification quotation.

Comment: As commented, this is JVM dependent - for example, what you state can't be correct for hostpot / Java 8 because there is no longer a Permgen at all...

Comment: This is still specific to the hotspot JVM.

Answer (score 6):

The [method area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4) (logically part of the heap) stores a lot of information about classes and interfaces in the JVM:

> ...stores per-class structures such as the run-time constant pool, field
>   and method data, and the code for methods and constructors, including
>   the special methods (§2.9) used in class and instance initialization
>   and interface initialization.

However:

> This specification does not mandate the location of the method area or
>   the policies used to manage compiled code.

Which means a particular JVM is free to store them wherever it pleases.